# android studio - package rename returns error

Tags: android, android-studio, aidl

I changed my project package name using refactor option. Renaming was successful but when i compiled it, it returned the following error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':compilePlayDebugAidl'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aidl.exe''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 1

How can i solve it?

PS: I have also changed the applicationID in build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error some time ago. Try the following:

- Build --> Clean Project
- Build --> Rebuild Project

Try to undo your changes and keep trying to compile it. If your project compiles at a specific point, make sure to let us know!

Cheers!

Comment: Thank u @DDerTyp. It helped me to find the error. The issue was, some function names didn't change. I changed it manually.